# angular2 filter/map results of http get into variables

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to take an object received from an http get and put it into 3 variables once obtained.

```
Data: [
{ 
    reportId: 1, 
    results1: [{
        name: "TotalReferralsMade",
        optionId: 3082,
        factor: 1,
        description: null
        }],
    results2: [ ],
    results3: [{
        name: "2014/15",
        dateRangeId: 469,
        dateFrom: "2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        dateTo: "2015-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"
}]}]
```

Above its the data I want into 3 variables. Below is the http request for the data.

```
public GetReportOptions (): Observable<ReportOptions[]> {
    return this._http.get('uri')
        .map((response: Response) => <ReportOptions[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("Options: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

So I call as part of a service to which a component is subscribed. Then in the component I call the data in ngOnChanges

```
getReportOptions(id: number) {
this._Service.GetReportOptions(id)
  .subscribe(options => this.results = options }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
}
```

This puts all the data into one object called results. I would like the data to go into results1, results2, results3. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep questioning if I understand your question correctly, mostly because it's less of an Angular2 question and more of a Javascript/Typescript question. I believe this is the answer you're looking for(If I am understanding the question and goal here).

```
getReportOptions(id: number) {
    this._Service.GetReportOptions(id)
           .subscribe(options => {
               //this.results = options; 
               this.results1 = options[0].results1;
               this.results2 = options[0].results2;
               this.results3 = options[0].results3;
           }}, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
}
```